# Android. Rounded rect

Tags: android, android-drawable, rect

How to create a rect with max rounded corners?

[image]

I tried:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <size android:width="44dp"
        android:height="100dp"/>

    <solid android:color="#8c51ff"/>
    <corners android:radius="24dp"/>


</shape>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "max rounded corners" ??

Comment: max value for radius. I can not set value bigger then 22dp. Nothing chages

Comment: Then you can use Oval instead of rectangle.

Comment: The edges should be straight. The edges are rounded at the oval

Answer (score 5):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
        android:shape="rectangle" > 

  <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="5dp" />

    <solid android:color="@color/pure_white_color" />  
    <corners android:radius="25dp"/>    
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="@color/text_view_border_color" />
  </shape>
```

Create a xml like "rounded.xml", and set background for the button as   `android:background="@drawable/rounded`"

Answer (score 1):

You can create a rectangle like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">

<!-- view background color -->
<solid
    android:color="@color/white" >
</solid>

<!-- If you want to add some padding -->
<padding
    android:left="5dp"
    android:top="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:bottom="5dp"    >
</padding>

<!-- Here is the corner radius -->
 <corners
    android:radius="6dp">
</corners> 

</shape>
```

Hope this answers your question.